# if else is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

The model:

```
function validate()
    {   
        $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('memberships');
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    function validate_admin()
    {   
        $this->db->where('adminname',$this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('admin');
        if($query->num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }   
    }
```

The controller

```
function validate_credentials()
    {
    $this->load->model('membership_model');

        if($this->membership_model->validate())
        {
        $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
        $get_profile_info = $this->db->get('memberships');
        if($get_profile_info->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach ($get_profile_info->result() as $row)
        {
            $info = array('firstname' => $row->firstname,
                            'lastname' => $row->lastname,
                            'email_address' => $row->email_address
                            );
        }
            $data = array(  
                'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'firstname' => $info['firstname'],
                'lastname' => $info['lastname'],
                'email_address' => $info['email_address'],
                'is_logged_in' => true
                );  
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            redirect('/site/main_menu');
        }}
        else if($this->membership_model->validate_admin())
        {
            echo "admin";
        }
        else
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

The if else if statement is not working correctly. The program test the first condition and if it returns false skips the second condition even if that is TRUE and execute the else statement. I'm not sure what is going worng here.

Comment: try var_dump on each validation without any if to see you are getting TRUE and make `else if` to `elseif`

Answer (score 0):

- Refactor your one controller method into different methods - one for Members and one for Admin to start. And because you are calling separate database tables would suggest having a separate model for each.
- Because you are interacting with a database table getting the profile information should happen in a model (not the controller).
- This is a personal preference but i would set the session data in a model as well. Also there might be issues with your foreach and then getting the value $info['first name'].
- Validate the form data first before sending to your database. Its safer and its better for your users - if they forget to put in the password you want to show them the form again with a helpful message.  http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

and remember when in doubt -- echo it out.